# Python BeautifulSoup include blank lines

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a website with python3 and BeautifullSoup and exporting into csv. The issue I am having is some elements are blank and when I print the page those elements are now missing. I would prefer it still prints even though it's blank. Due to this in my csv file the rows do not match with the columns when an element is blank. I am sure if I can get the print working as expected I can fix the issue in my csv file.

Example html code

```
<tr><td>item1</td><td>server11</td><td>env</td><td>uptime</td></tr>
<tr><td>item2</td><td></td><td>env</td><td>uptime</td></tr>
```

As you can see item2 has td tag which is blank

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
for s in soup.findAll('tr'):
    print(s.get_text(","))
```

The output is

```
item1,server11,env,uptime
item2,env,uptime
```

However I would the output to look like this

```
item1,server11,env,uptime
item2,,env,uptime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.join` to join texts from all `<td>`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<tr><td>item1</td><td>server11</td><td>env</td><td>uptime</td></tr>
<tr><td>item2</td><td></td><td>env</td><td>uptime</td></tr>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.select('tr'):
    print(','.join(td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')))
```

Prints:

```
item1,server11,env,uptime
item2,,env,uptime
```